# How to dynamically address vars with a string?

Tags: java, android

Comming from Actionscript 3, Java seems to be a bit different here:

Having three Buttons, Button btn0; Button btn1; Button btn2;
I want to iterate through them setting onClickListeners() like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {    
    this["btn"+i].setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

is that even possible?

Comment: Why not use a standard array? Remember that Java lacks such runtime concessions, replacing them with speed and code safety.

Comment: Yeah I know TIM TOADY, but I am curious if it's even possible with java.

Comment: First of all, let's not start calling each other names here. Second, it is possible with something called reflection, but the drawbacks, complex implementation, and performance losses due to reflection outweigh the benefits.

Comment: thanks. fyi tim toady means There's more than one way to do it ;)

Comment: @Michael - pretty much any time you want one of these "dynamic" variable thingies (how's that for technical terms?) in Java, use a Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you're asking about the data structures available in Java, let's see some options. It's possible to reproduce the behavior in your code if you use a `Map`:

```
// instantiate the map
Map<String, Button> map = new HashMap<String, Button>();
// fill the map
map.put("btn0", new Button());
// later on, retrieve the button given its name
map.get("btn" + i).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Alternatively, you could simply use the index as identifier, in which case it's better to use a `List`:

```
// instantiate the list
List<Button> list = new ArrayList<Button>();
// fill the list
list.add(new Button());
// later on, retrieve the button given its index
list.get(i).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Or if the number of buttons is fixed and known beforehand, use an array:

```
// instantiate the array
Button[] array = new Button[3];
// fill the array
array[0] = new Button();
// later on, retrieve the button given its index
array[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: +1 Map is a great idea and fits OP needs.  Note that Components also have a name so, for completeness, it's good to put that id (e.g. "btn1") there as well.